# How to get a medium-sized otimes

Tags: symbols

What is a good way to get an O-times between the sizes of `\otimes` and `\bigotimes`? I should add that I want it to act as a math operator as in `\bigotimes` (so that I can use subscripts below it.)

I managed to get it by 

`\DeclareMathOperator*{\Motimes}{\raisebox{-0.25ex}{\scalebox{1.2}{$\bigotimes$}}}`

using one of the approaches here:
[A medium dot in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81729/a-medium-dot-in-math-mode)

I was wondering if there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your declaration you get a symbol that is *bigger* than `\bigotimes`...

Assuming that you *really* want a symbol between the sizes of `\otimes` and `\bigotimes` you can declare it as

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Motimes}{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\bigotimes$}}}}
```

The following MWE shows the difference between it and `\bigotimes`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Motimes}{\text{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\bigotimes$}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\bigotimes_{i=1}^{k}V_i \qquad A \bigotimes B_{A \bigotimes B_{A \bigotimes B}}
\]

\bigskip

\[
\Motimes_{i=1}^{k}V_i \qquad A\Motimes B_{A \Motimes B_{A \Motimes B}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You could use the `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` primitives to align the rescaled symbol on the math axis; doing so would dispense with the guesswork associated with the `\raisebox` method.

Comment: @Mico Do you mean something like `\DeclareMathOperator*{\Motimes}{\text{$\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.8}{$\bigotimes$}}}$}}`? To be honest, I prefer the symbol a bit higher.

Comment: Yes, except that I think the outer `\text{$` and `$}` group isn't strictly necessary, right? About the desirability of placing the symbol a bit higher: That's a matter of taste, I suppose, and we all know what they say about arguing about tastes...

Comment: @Mico but if you remove the outer `\text{$` and `$}` group the symbol is quite smaller and increasing the scale it looks bad.

Comment: Did you compute the ration 0.25ex / 0.8, or is it just by chance, because it "looks good" or "right"?

Comment: @Clément because it "looks good"

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
\newcommand{\sbigotimes}{%
  \mathop{\mathchoice{\textstyle\bigotimes}{\bigotimes}{\bigotimes}{\bigotimes}}%
}
```

and

```
\[
\sbigotimes_{i=1}^n A_i\otimes B
\]
```

would produce

[image]

to be compared with the original (with `\bigotimes`)

[image]

I suggest an “abstract” version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makesmalleroperator}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname saved\string#1\endcsname#1% save the old command
  \def#1{\mathop{\small@mathchoice#1}}% redefine it
}
\def\small@mathchoice#1{%
  \mathchoice{\textstyle\@nameuse{saved\string#1}}%
             {\@nameuse{saved\string#1}}%
             {\@nameuse{saved\string#1}}%
             {\@nameuse{saved\string#1}}%
}
\makeatother

% now we declare what operators should be treated like this
\makesmalleroperator\bigotimes

\begin{document}

\[
\bigotimes_{i=1}^n A_i\otimes B
\]

\end{document}
```

This will give the same result as above with `\sbigotimes`. What are the advantages?

1. You can do the same for `\bigvee`, `\bigwedge` and all the operators you need with a single line for each of them.
2. You can use the normal names; if you change your mind or have to submit the document somewhere, you can simply remove the definitions and the calls to `\makesmalleroperator`

The same size as in display math will be used for inline usage.